# Django Efficient One-to-Many Chain Lookup

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the below data structure:

```
class File(models.Model):
    dataset = models.ForeignKey(Dataset)

class Dataset(models.Model):
    mission = models.ForeignKey(Mission)

class Mission(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)

class Project(models.Model):
    pass
```

I'd like to efficiently decide if a Project contains any files. Starting from a single `Project` object, how do I obtain a list of all the related files?

I understand `project.mission_set.all()` would get me the first layer, but I don't know how to efficiently chain the queries.

Comment: According to your schema one `Project` can have one `File`, but a `File` can have several `Project`s? is it correct?

Comment: No, the table may be unclear. Each File links to single Dataset, to a single mission to a single Project.

Each Project can have multiple missions, which may have multiple datasets, which may contain multiple files.

Comment: I've edited the question for clarity

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know what `Files` instances are related to `my_project` instance you can access it as follows:

```
my_project = Project.objects.create()

File.objects.filter(dataset__mission__project=my_project)
```

In order to know the quantity you can do:

```
File.objects.filter(dataset__mission__project=project).count()
```

Comment: Thank you. I was not approaching the problem correctly. What I wanted was to filter out the projects with no files in a template. My final solution was `if my_project.id in ClientFile.objects.values_list('dataset__mission__project_id', flat=True).distinct()`